# How to remove padding around Firefox navigation bar

Tags: firefox, user-interface

I want to remove the obtrusive padding, here highlighted in red:

[image]

I want to reduce the height between the red bars, to remove the unused space.

Comment: See if [this post](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/952811) from Firefox works

Answer (score 0):

add this to userChrome.css in your profile folder

```
#nav-bar
{
        padding-bottom: 0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Firefox cannot dynamically update this width.  You should be able to click-n-drag teh right hand end of the address bar if you want to shrink it?  I know this is possible on my win7, win 8.1 and Kali linux boxes so i see no reason why this wouldn't work for you.

Edit: after being pointed out to me that this was a height, not a idth question and the question also being updated to reflect this more clearly: support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/952811  Here is your answer.  You can edit the user css config file.

Comment: Sorry my post must be unclear: I want to reduce the HEIGHT between the bars, not the length of the bar itself. I'm going to try to clarify my question.

Comment: Apologies, i misread your question... https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/952811  You can use the user css file to accomplish this.

Comment: Link-only answers are a no-no; please include pertinent information directly in your answers.